# Delay in delivering messages with Mailscanner and Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, mailscanner

With Mailscanner (v4.85.2) and Postfix (v2.11.1-1) on Ubuntu mail is being delivered, but there are times where messages sit on the incoming queue after mailscanner has scanned them for right at 5 minutes before being delivered (in my case I'm delivering to Cyrus IMAP, but I believe that's inconsequential as the problem is that postfix isn't trying to deliver them until a certain timeout occurs).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point (in 2013, I believe), the postfix package changed the entry for `qmgr` from `fifo` to `unix` in `master.cf` (in `/etc/postfix` on my system). Because of this change, the delay was introduced. You probably also have this message in your mail log: `KickMessage failed as couldn't write to /var/spool/postfix/public/qmgr`

To fix this, change the `qmgr` entry in `master.cf` from:

```
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
```

to

```
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
```

and reload postfix.

Thanks to the [this mailscanner list thread](http://lists.mailscanner.info/pipermail/mailscanner/2013-April/100578.html) for providing the answer.

Comment: For changes in `master.cf` a restart is needed AFAIK.

Comment: @sebix Just FYI, according to the documentation for master (5) on Linux, a postfix reload is sufficient:  'After changing master.cf you must execute "postfix reload" to reload the configuration.'

Comment: You seem to be right on that. I think, when I started with postfix, this wasn't the case.